# Snake size not increasing after eating food?

Tags: javascript

Relevant code:

```
if (food.x === snake[0].x && food.y === snake[0].y) {
    // increase the size of the snake
    snake.push({
      x: snake[snake.length - 1].x,
      y: snake[snake.length - 1].y
    });
```

where snake is an array of objects. Each object is x and y coordinates of snake position and food is an object with x and y coordinates randomly placed.

I've tried to first unshift then pop the array snake, but it didn't work.

Comment: Works fine for me - https://codepen.io/ilorwork/pen/oNMOwmg

Comment: https://codepen.io/pelko/pen/bGjZxJy

Not working for me though.

Comment: @I.sh. could you take a look at this?